# VB.NET to connect to an Online SQL Server 2008

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I can connect with VB.net to SQL Server via using connection Strings

```
  Dim Sqlconn As New SqlConnection("Server=:serverip:;Database=:DB:; uid= :uid:; pwd=:pwd:;")
```

I use this to connect locally (in the office).

my question: is there a way for me to connect in an ONLINE manner? ie I will connect my application from two far locations, from the United States to the SQL Server which is in the Philippines.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the "server = ;" part of the connection string.

Any help is dearly appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: Try http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure how that helps me. It doesn't distinguish which of the following connection strings is for online connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the IP could be of any location. Just replace the IP of your connection string and it will work for you. NO difference in online and offline server.

The server IP will be your Data source which is the combination of the IP and the instance name. If it is the default instance then only ip will do for you but if it is the user defined instance then you have to mention the ip\instance name too.

Comment: thank you for the reply. But how will I know exactly which IP to replace on the "Server =serverip;" part. 
I understand you can basically just ipconfig within your server, but that didn't work (I'm thinking that isn't the way to do it either, since there must be some sort of registration that makes sure each IP is unique online)

Comment: @Malky.Kid online IP,s are static IP and those are unique you dont need to worry about that.

Comment: okay, so how will I know what the online IP of my server is? It's running windows server 2008

Answer (score 1):

An online connection string is no different from a local one. Just replace the `serverip` part with the **public facing IP** address of your "online" server.

If your machine can be accessed via the internet it will have an IP address on the local network and an IP address that it uses on the Public (Internet) side.

You will need to request a static IP address from your ISP, or else this public IP address may change over time and your connection will break. There is usually a charge for this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. By "Public Facing IP", what do you mean?

Comment: How will I know the "Public facing IP" of my server?

Comment: You need a static IP address from your ISP. This video may be of use: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOUDdUJ5BLY

Comment: Thanks for the video. It all boils down to the "Port Forwarding" thing that you have to do with your Router, which my colleagues mention that it isn't available at our router.. does this mean I'm screwed?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using a VPN Software. HAMACHI. It provided our server with a unique Public IP which I then used as input for the "Server=;" requirement of the connection string. 
Might help some people who are having the same problems, but I will still welcome new answers.